# Link two HTML divs' dimensions to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

If I have div **A** and div **B**, is there a way to say `A.width = b.width = MAX(a.width, b.width)` ?  That is, whichever has the largest inner content would dictate how large both are.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is with columns - **left**, **middle**, and **right**.  I want the left and right to be the same **fixed width** (but this could vary depending on their content).

Comment: any problem in using css3 flexible boxes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use CSS to achieve this. However, if there is a way to do it with a JS-based solution. Here I am using jQuery. Let's say you have two divs, with classes `a` and `b` respectively.

```
$(function() {
    function equalizeSize($ele) {
        if($ele.length > 1) {
            // Let CSS automatically calculate natural width first
            $ele.css({ width: 'auto' });

            // And then we fetch the newly calculated widths
            var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, $ele.map(function(){ return $(this).outerWidth(); }).get());
            $ele.css({ width: maxWidth });
        }
    }

    // Run when DOM is ready
    equalizeSize($('.a, .b'));

    // Run again when viewport has been resized, which **may** affect your div width.
    // This is optional, but good to have
    // ps: You might want to look into throttling the resize function
    $(window).resize(equalizeSize($('.a, .b')));
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/N4MMg/

The advantages of this simple function:

1. Allows you to dictate what elements you want to equalize widths with.
2. Uses the `.map()` function to construct an array, which we then use `Math.max.apply` to get the maximum value in the array
3. Forces automatic calculation of width when the function first fires (especially when resizing the viewport)
4. Allows you to call to recalculate the size again, using the handler `equalizeSize()` when you change the content in the divs... you can call the function again, say, after an AJAX call that appends content to either element.

Comment: This is really cool, and answers a lot of questions I have.  The value returned by width() appears to be incorrect (either by units or otherwise).  I'll keep playing with it.

edit: changed to outerWidth() and the code works. Is this expected?

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense, especially when you have declared `box-sizing: border-box` for the `<div>` and they have paddings in their styles.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want from the description. but I can rewrite your code this way.

```
  var properWidth = Math.max($("#a").width(), $("#b").width());
  $("#a").css("width", properWidth + "px");
  $("#b").css("width", properWidth + "px");
```

I am not sure if it is this kind of solution you want.

Comment: Hmm that might be the best solution.  Is there a way to do that implicitly?  Like if b changes later?

Comment: @xtravar that would be JavaScript (jQuery) so would have to be called whenever the size of one of your divs changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to do it like that. But why not make a default function to set the size:

```
function changeSize(w, h)
{
    A.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+w+'; height:'+h);
    b.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+w+'; height:'+h);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/ER2zZ/